# Prove that any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

Prove that any two cylic groups of the same ordr are isomorphic

Comment: Any finite cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Try to prove this by defining an isomorphism from  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$. For infinite groups, replace $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Let $|<x>|=|<y>|$ then define a map $x^i\mapsto y^i$. Then show that it is an isomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Say $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two cyclic groups of order $n$, with generators $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively, the define

$\phi(g_1^k)=g_2^k$

for all $n\geq k>0$ .

It would define an isomorphism from the group $G_1$ to $G_2$.

Comment: Thnkss..i shell try